# Ember.js findQuery didn't work

Tags: ember.js

model:

```
 App.Attack = DS.Model.extend({
        user: DS.belongsTo('user'),
        post: DS.belongsTo('post'),
        damage: DS.attr('integer')
    });
```

controller:

```
store.findQuery('attack',{user: {{Auth::user()->id}},post: this.get('id')}).then(function (attack){
    return false;
},function(error) {
    return true;
  });
```

the data is exist but it always return true, please help

Comment: What does your javascript look like in the browser, is `{{Auth::user()->id}}` part of another templating engine, and is it being calculated correctly?  You should be return a collection from this rest endpoint.

Comment: yes, ít's blade template and it works correctly, findquery will work for damage attr but user and post are not a normal attr as you can see, so I think this is the problem but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Will you show the json being returned and the final javascript, not the template?

Comment: it return true because of this part
function(error) {
    return true;
  });
meaning it couldn't find any record

Comment: No, it returns true because it failed processing the response.

Comment: @Kingpin2k do you know how to fix it? please help me, I don't want to write ugly code to get pass this

Comment: you could start with showing the json being returned, and what the javascript looks like in page, not in template.